# java putting interest rate on my mortgage calculator

Tags: java

I made a code to calculate the monthly mortgage payment. Here is part of my code->

```
public static void printAmortizationSchedule(double principal, double annualInterestRate,
    int numYears) {

        double interestPaid, principalPaid, newBalance;
        double monthlyInterestRate, monthlyPayment;
        int month;
        int numMonths = numYears * 12;

        monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12;
        monthlyPayment      = monthlyPayment(principal, monthlyInterestRate, numYears);
        System.out.format("Your monthly Payment is: %8.2f%n", monthlyPayment);

        for (month = 1; month <= numMonths; month++) {
            // Compute amount paid and new balance for each payment period
            interestPaid  = principal      * (monthlyInterestRate / 100);
            principalPaid = monthlyPayment - interestPaid;
            newBalance    = principal      - principalPaid;

            // Update the balance
            principal = newBalance;

        }
    }

    static double monthlyPayment(double loanAmount, double monthlyInterestRate, int numberOfYears) {
        monthlyInterestRate /= 100;  
        return loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate /
        ( 1 - 1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfYears * 12) );
    }
```

now, I need to add code that
1.The principal amount must be a non-negative number.

2. The mortgage payment will be determined by one of these amounts:

•   1 year 3.5%
•   2 year 3.9%
•   3 year 4.4%
•   5 year 5.0%
•   10 year 6.0%

I think I need to use do while statement, or if else code. However, I'm struggling to find where to put. Please help me!

Comment: why does `printAmortizationSchedule` take the `annualInterestRate` if it will be calculated based upon the number of years?

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you're dealing with a condition:

- *if* the principal amount is negative, *then* don't perform the calculation, otherwise, proceed with the calculation.
- *if* the mortgage is for n years *then* use r rate.

Hence, you'd use the if-then-else construct.

For the principle amount, check it early; It doesn't make sense to perform computations only to throw it all away because they are invalid. You can throw an exception to indicate the invalid input, a negative principal.

For the rate you just need to make sure you select the right one (with if-then-else) before you use it.